# how to ensure certain http headers are present in the response

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm new to spring, so please excuse my ignorance.

I want to ensure that every response from my application contains the following headers:

```
Content-Type → application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date →Tue, 22 Nov 2016 16:30:21 GMT
```

is there a easy way of doing this, which I am missing? any advice or possible solutions would be great. Thanks all :)

Comment: Does http://mtyurt.net/2015/07/20/spring-modify-response-headers-after-processing/ help you?

Comment: yeah I saw that, but this seems like overkill, and is not exactly the same scenario. I want to ensure these headers are present on every response. There must be a much simpler way of achieving this, maybe in the config ??

Comment: Do you have access to response object?

Comment: yep, am "returning" responseEntity<response object>(response object,  HttpStatus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, I solved this by creating a custom filter like so :

```
@Component
public class ResponseHeaderFilter implements Filter {
  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    String dateString = simpleDateFormat.format(UnixTime.now() * 1000);

    response.setHeader("Date", dateString);
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

    chain.doFilter(req, resp);

  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {

  }
}
```

this then created another problem with another custom filter in the code base. so I solve this additional problem with the help of this blog post: 
http://mtyurt.net/2015/07/15/spring-how-to-insert-a-filter-before-springsecurityfilterchain/ . Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is going to work for you or not, because i cannot test it. the thing that I am sure of, is that you can do it, and the easiest way is :

create a spring interceptor and override `postHandle` methode.

try this out:

Interceptor class :

package com.mkyong.common.interceptor;

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{


    public void postHandle(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView)
        throws Exception {

        response.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    }
}
```

here is the list of header [fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) you can set, and dont forget to declare this class as spring bean.

```
<interceptors>
        <interceptor>
            <mapping path="/**" />
            <beans:bean class="package.MyInterceptor"></beans:bean>
        </interceptor>
</interceptors>
```

Comment: yeah, thanks, would be a great solution, but doesn't seem to work maybe for the reason in the link provided above.

Comment: what link ?? `<prop key="[yourmapping]">[yourcontroller]</prop>`